# UIButton image working on simulator but not on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an app where there is a `UITableView` populated UIButtons that are created programatically. The code below shows how one `UIButton` is created.

It works perfectly on the simulator but not on the device. On the simulator the buttons are displayed with the **buttonImage.png** shown but on the device the image is not there. All other aspects of the buttons are correct.

The image has been added to the resources correctly as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell ==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0f green:73/255.0f blue:17/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:20];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//more buttons created as needed

NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:button];
//more buttons added to array as needed

[cell addSubview:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Try `[cell.contentview addSubview:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: Hey ! you must check one silly thing may be this will be you problem.Check case of name it should be the same. For example:-

buttonImage or buttonimage  it should be the same name with same case.Otherwise it will show it in simulator not on device .

Comment: This may be problem in your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6773296/817365

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your image name, because simulator is not case sensitive but the device is case sensitive.

Comment: I did as soon as it allowed me to :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem when I renamed an icon in my application, using the XCode navigator window. All was fine in the simulator, but when I (eventually) tested on my device the icon would not show up. I verified the spelling, and case, numerous times (after reading the above accepted answer), and I even copy/pasted the icon name over... no dice.

I tried cleaning the app and rebuild... no dice.

Finally I closed XCode completely and relaunched from 'Launchpad',... and it worked.

It was a frustrating hour. Feels, to me, like there's a bug in there somewhere.

Comment: After checking the spelling (as suggested in the accepted answer), I tried this recommendation. I also did a clean/build after restarting XCode, for good measure. It worked after that. Thanks for the hint. Saved me hours of debugging.

Comment: Note: Changing the caption do not work until you do a "Product ->Clean" to force the compiler to rebuild the asset catalog the next time you build.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not at fault. I am sure you have tested your app on non retina simulator & it is showing button.

So now when you test it on device, I am sure you are testing on a retina device & you have not provided the 2x version of your button image.

Solution:: add a 2x version of image to your resource.

Example:: yourImage.png (32x32), then add another image to resource with name
 yourImage@2x.png (64x64)

That solves your problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: one capital letter was the problem - see ticked answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: this solution was helpful for my apple watch app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make these changes in your code:

Change `control event`

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchInside];
```

Add Button in content view of cell

```
[cell.contentview addSubview:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove installed app from device, and run it again

Comment: one capital letter was the problem - see ticked answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check spelling and also allow user interaction by `button.allowUserInteraction = true`